# File reading, encryption, and decompression

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

I am working on a cryptography project capable of encrypting files of smallish sizes (we don't know the limit). Being new to python and coding in general I've run into a few issues. [My code is here.](http://pastebin.com/G2s84Jzc)

The basics of my code is that I convert the file into its byte representation, then convert the bytes into bits and then the bits into 6-bit integers for the sake of space and speed. We run the 6-bit integers through a small compression program. The program compresses eight consecutive integers in this fashion:

```
sumInts=sum(ints[i]*64**i)
```

The resulting list is then run through the encryption algorithm the rest of my group is creating. The new data can then be run through a decryption algorithm that they are also creating. The issue occurs when decompressing the message. The program runs fine for most of the compressed data, but then around the last few large compressed integers the program randomly stops and leaves just a large, half-decompressed number. I have no clue where the issue in my code is for this part.

The other issue I am having is that we intend to use this on any given file. However when the data is all reassembled I would imagine that it would need to be recompiled in order to revert back into its original file-type. Is there any way to bypass this in python?

This is my first post here so forgive any formatting errors or blatant rule breaking I may have done.

EDIT: I managed to fix it through the help of a math professor I am working with. I'm not exactly sure what the error in the code was, [but the new fixed code is here.](http://pastebin.com/TBUCGtW6) The professor also said I didn't need to worry about recompiling, so I will just store the results in a .txt file. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: you should probably try putting some print statements in to figure out where your code is stoping at ... then you should create a small example that demonstrates the issue ... as the one line of code and an english explanation of your algorithm gives us no Idea where you may have gone wrong ... are you sure its a perfect compression algorithm(i.e. no data is lost?)?

Comment: Why are you even inventing your own crypto algorithm? This is kind of always a bad idea. There are Python modules you can use that have implemented the good known algorithms already.

Comment: also the one line of code you do provide looks very fissy
assuming `ints[i]` is a list of 8 integers `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` ... that line will sum a repeating list of those numbers that is 64**i long ... assuming i is 1 that would be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,64 times!!]` then summing them ... that does not seem like a perfect compression at all

Comment: @ChristofferKarlsson the idea that all the good crypto has already been invented is definitely false (that said I am inclined to agree with you,)Im guessing this is an assignment of some sort :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I never said they've been *invented*, only that the good known ones has been *implemented*. Two different words :)
But yeah, that reason you mention makes sense though.

Comment: heh fair enough ... I dunno that this is a known algorithm that he is trying to implement (which makes me even more suspicious that its just a broken algorithm)